# private or unknown calls on call logs

Tags: push-notifications

I have noticed that when I receive a call from a private or unknown number, the notification does not appear on my call log list. How can I get a private or unknown number call I receive to appear on my calling log list?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may not register into the log because there is nothing to register. There is little, if any, data you can collect from a private call log.

The other thing is possibly your priority mode on your android. That could cause interference. Maybe. Not for sure on the last part but it is worth a shot. Anyways, just my 2 cents.